# Get events according to user's time zone not DB + Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I have a three events. They contains `start_time` of show.

But the problem what I am facing is with **time zone**. Value saved in db is in UTC as Rails default behaviour.

**How it works:** User can select date time from date time picker.

As per user, he choosed `2017-04-08 04:00:00` IST, but event saved in database is `2017-04-07 21:30:00` UTC.

**Scenario**: When user trying to fetch events for `8th April`, it returns nothing because there are no events for `8th April` according to Database.

In my case **Time zone** could be anything like:

```
1) Mumbai                       (+05:30)
2) Pacific Time (US & Canada)   (-08:00)
```

So in these cases, I will never get the correct events according to user's time zone.

Below events are created for `8th April` but saved as `7th April` so whenever user come and see his event for the in calender, it never appeared.

```
<event id: "1250", title: "lgkg", description: nil, created_by: "12345", account_id: "35", repeat: true, start_time: "2017-04-07 21:30:00", created_at: "2017-04-07 05:17:33", updated_at: "2017-04-07 05:17:33">

<event id: "1251", title: "lgkg", description: nil, created_by: "12345", account_id: "35", repeat: true, start_time: "2017-04-07 21:30:00", created_at: "2017-04-07 05:20:43", updated_at: "2017-04-07 05:20:43">

<event id: "1252", title: "lgkg", description: nil, created_by: "12345", account_id: "35", repeat: true, start_time: "2017-04-07 21:30:00", created_at: "2017-04-07 05:25:03", updated_at: "2017-04-07 05:25:03">
```

**Help:**

Need help to find a solution for fetch the events correctly according to user's time zone.

**Required information:**

Currently `Account` has one column `time_zone`. We can use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you basically needed to convert the DateTime to UTC first:

```
Time.zone = current_account.time_zone
utc_time = Time.parse(picked_time).utc
events = Event.where("start_time > ?", utc_time)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to store the user's timezone and use AT TIMEZONE see: [Section 9.9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

Note that postgresql ALWAYS stores timestamp with timezone as UTC.